# Comparing strings to assign values based on a logical operator

Tags: r, date, compare, operators, character

I'm trying to create a column of firm closure dates according to the date of their last account activity, and if the firm isn't closed (i.e., if `firms.df$Status != "Dead"`) insert a "0" instead. Here's the code:

```
## create column of company failure dates
firms.df <- within(firms.df, ifelse(firms.df$Status == "Dead", 
                        FailDate <- ifelse(!is.na(AccountName), LastAction, FirstAction),        
                        FailDate <- 0))

 firms.df$FailDate <- as.Date(firms.df$FailDate, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

The problem is that it currently returns a "0" for each cell. If I remove the initial operator that checks whether firms.df$Status == "Dead", it returns the appropriate values from LastAction and FirstAction (as intended).

There's something wrong with the logical operator that looks to see if `firms.df$Status == "Dead"`, but I can't figure it out. I've tried using `Status %in% c("Dead")` as well, but to no avail. Status and AccountName are both characters, and LastAction and FirstAction are both dates.

Bonus points if you can figure how to format FailDate as a Date without the extra line at the bottom. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you run `sapply(firms.df, class)` and provide the output.

Comment: Could you elaborate, what code would you use in place of `class`?

Comment: if you run `sapply(firms.df, class)` exactly as it is (just copy/past) it will tell you what kind of data you have in each column of your dataframe. If alternatively try copy/pasting this `class(firms.df$Status)` - if it returns `factor` you will need to convert it to character with `firms.df$Status <- as.characater(firms.df$Status)`

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`, much faster and cleaner solution:

```
# convert to data table
setDT(firms.df)

# subset by rows and apply the condition
firms.df[Status == 'Dead', FailDate := ifelse(!is.na(AccountName), LastAction, FirstAction)]
firms.df[Status != 'Dead', FailDate := 0]
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks. Is there any reason to convert it back to a data frame after adding the FailDate column?

Comment: data.table is actually a data frame only but with a lot more optimized for speed performance. If you are not comfortable with data.table,  you can do setDF() or else you can do a quick coffee time read here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html

Comment: What would the code look like to do this in a dataframe?